# How to get ngmodel under ngrepeat binding to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a json data from a api call which is like below procution_volumes array.

```
"production_volumes = [{period:'2014Q4', volume:'200', comment:'nothing'},{period:'2014Q2', volume:'300', comment:'something'},{period:'2014Q1', volume:'500', comment:'search'}]"
```

I want this to show in table form where users can update data. Table code is below

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>Year</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Quarter</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Volume</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Comment</strong></th>
          <th class="text-right"><strong>Delete</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="production in production_volumes">
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <select style="min-width: 140px;" class="select_field form-control">
              <option ng-repeat="period_year in period_years" value="{{period_year}}" ng-model="production.period.split('Q')[0]" ng-selected="production.period.indexOf(production.period)!=-1">{{period.year}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <select style="min-width: 140px;" class="select_field form-control">
              <option ng-repeat="period_quater in period_quaters" value="{{period_quater}}" ng-model="production.period.split('Q')" ng-selected="production.period.indexOf('Q'+period_year)!=-1">{{production.period.split("Q")[1]}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50" ng-pattern="" ng-model="production.volume">
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50" ng-pattern="" ng-model="production.comment">
          </td>
          <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(12-project_details.production_volumes.length) track by $index">
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <select style="min-width: 140px;" class="select_field form-control" ng-model="">
              <option ng-repeat="period_year in period_years" value="{{period_year}}">{{period_year}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <select style="min-width: 140px;" class="select_field form-control" ng-model="">
              <option ng-repeat="period_quater in period_quaters" value="{{period_quater}}">{{period_quater}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50">
          </td>
          <td class="vertical-align-top">
            <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50">
          </td>
          <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <input type="checkbox" class="">
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

In js file in the same controller, i am unable to bind the $scope.production.volume and $scope.production.comment. Its giving me error of $scope.production is not defined. when i user a different ng-model instead of production.volume, then data is not showing in view. What would be the ideal solution where i can display data from json and send any updated data back to json.

Fiddle link for your reference [http://jsfiddle.net/reachsampathreddy/1gxgsrqm](http://jsfiddle.net/reachsampathreddy/1gxgsrqm/)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in an ng-repeat and the volume and comment properties are members of the production object created via the ng-repeat. There's no need to try to make use of the index when binding. Just using:

```
<td class="vertical-align-top">
    <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="production.volume">
</td>
<td class="vertical-align-top">
    <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="production.comment">
</td>
```

works just fine.

Comment: That way i am able to display data of array but not able to bind to scope to send data back when user submits.

Comment: Why not? Angular keeps track of where it came from and updates it in the model? I added a submit button and just put a debugger line in it and inspected the scope and the values are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have declared the production in ng-repeat it no more related to js file. if you want to access the updated volume and comment just use the ng-change() .

ex:

```html
  <input type="text" class="input_field form-control" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="production.volume" ng-change="getTheChangedValue(production.volume)">
</td>
```

in your js file create getTheChangedValue() function and console your changed value.

if you want to post the database you don't need to manually change it in your js file, Angular has watchers what ever you change in the view it will automatically updated in the model.

Comment: At the end of the table there is a submit button which i missed here. On submit i have created a function in controller where i am trying to contruct array with existing and updated fields to data variable and sending that in to api call. but problem is when is declare var data = { "volume" = $scope.production.volume, "comment" = $scope.production.comment } .. i am getting error of $scope.production is not defined as its dynamically generated using ng-repeat. I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: can you please provide the complete code snippet? if you want you can copy the original array in temp variable using angular.copy(). do one thing, take a copy of original array like original_production_volumes, any how the modified values will be in production_volumes, so you have both, you can use either you want.